# SmartThings WebCoRE Piston alert only once an hour

Tags: samsung-smartthings

I have a WebCoRE piston that looks something like this.

```
if
   Device temperature changes
then
   do   Send SMS notification "Test message" to 1234567890;
   do   Wait 60 minutes;
else
end if;
end execute;
```

The Device temperature changes every few minutes, but I want to get notified of that only every hour.

I thought that the "Wait 60 minutes" line would do that trick, but I continue to get a text every ~5 minutes.

I can't find an example of how to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Does it do 10 minutes if you change it to Wait 10 minutes; ?

Comment: No. In real life I actually have it set to 15 minutes. I just wanted the example to match the title :-)

Comment: See if this helps:
https://community.smartthings.com/t/webcore-wait-problem/115705/24